# .js.coffee file not running in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a simple javascript file based on the #381 railscast episode.  When I place an alert in my javascript file, though, it does not appear when I load my page.  I am sure that the file itself is loaded as I checked in the view source.  Any ideas why it isn't loading?

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require js-routes
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= requre_self
//= require_tree .
```

images.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  alert("hello world")
  $('#new_image').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
```

Comment: are there any javascript warnings/errors on the page?

Comment: I don't believe so:
Started GET "/assets/images.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-12 11:34:50 -0500
Served asset /images.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: What about the JS console in the browser?

Comment: I am getting two errors for other javascript files, one having to do with activeadmin (Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker') and one gon error (Uncaught ReferenceError: gon is not defined ).  Would this prevent the images.js file from running?

Comment: Yes, it could if those errors are occurring before the alert is executed. Try removing the related files from application.js. You could also try removing `require_tree .` which recursively includes all files in app/assets/javascripts, but you'll have to manually add all files that need to be included if you do this.

Comment: yes, you're right!  I had to remove 'require_tree .' since this causes some issues with active admin.  I then just added 'require images' to include my own model, an dit worked.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joshua Rieken make your commet an answer. scientiffic accept the answer when it is made. It's better for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the files causing JS errors from application.js. You could also try removing `require_tree .` which recursively includes all files in app/assets/javascripts, but you'll have to manually add all files that need to be included if you do this.